# Proper web server setup

Tags: web-server, configuration, process

I just got myself a slicehost basic slice to play around with so I can learn how to setup web-servers.

I have Ubuntu 10.04.2 installed on the server.

I was able to successfully get the server up and running from scratch, these were the things I did - following [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-setup-a-dedicated-web-server-for-free/). I know this is probably just a starters tutorial, so, I was wondering if you guys can tell me what you like to do while setting up production servers.

These are the steps that were followed :

Update and Upgrade Ubuntu

`sudo apt-get install apache2 php5-mysql libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server`

Backup a copy of and edit **apache2.conf** Set : 
'ServerTokens Full' to 'ServerTokens Prod'
'ServerSignature On' to 'ServerSignature Off'

Backup **php.ini** and then Change “expose_php = On” to “expose_php = Off”

Restart Apache

Install Shorewall firewall

Configure Shorewall to only accept HTTP and SSH connections(in the rules file)

Enable shorewall on startup

Add the website to the server :

```
sudo usermod -g www-data root
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www
```

Edit : 
More steps : 
1) Create another user account and Disable the root account. 
2) Change the port for ssh.

Please feel free to add the things are left out/done wrong that you would otherwise do for a production server. Much appriciated, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your installation is ok.

If you use PHP you can use "apc" for php caching for better performance:

```
apt-get install php-apc
```